# Razor Pages: Persistent Model Data after second Post button

Tags: asp.net-core, post, razor-pages

I'm newbie to Razor Pages; I have a page of Employee Data (EmpId, EmpName, Leave Balance), with a button to Calculate the Leave Balance, and set the value to the property (Leave Balance). After calculating the leave balance, the user has to send a verification code to his email before he finally submits to his manager. Unfortunately in the second submit button event, and after postback the whole page, the emp object becomes null!. the following code is an illustration of my code (not the actual code):

```
public class Index2Model : PageModel
{
    [BindProperty]
    public Employee Emp { get; set; }
    public IActionResult OnGet()
    {
        if (Emp ==null)
            Emp = new Employee {EmpId=1,EmpName="Youssef", };

        return Page();
    }

    public IActionResult OnPostSubmit1()
    {
        //Code to calculate the employee leave balance
        Emp.LeaveBalance = 30;
        return Page();
    }
    public IActionResult OnPostSubmit2()
    {
        //After calling the Submit button, Emp object is null
        return Page();
    }
}
```

And this is the HTML code:

```html
@page
@model DIWEB.Pages.Index2Model
@{
}
<div>
    <form method="post">
        @Html.DisplayNameFor(model => model.Emp.EmpName)
        @Html.DisplayFor(model => model.Emp.EmpName)
        <br />
        @Html.DisplayNameFor(model => model.Emp.LeaveBalance)
        @Html.DisplayFor(model => model.Emp.LeaveBalance)
        <br />
        <input type="submit" value="Submit1" asp-page-handler="Submit1" />
        <br />
        <input type="submit" value="Submit2" asp-page-handler="Submit2" />
    </form>

</div>
```

Any advise please.

Answer (score 0):

Form will not submit the display text, you may set a hidden input for each property:

```
<form method="post">
    <input type="hidden" asp-for="Emp.EmpId" />

    @Html.DisplayNameFor(model => model.Emp.EmpName)
    @Html.DisplayFor(model => model.Emp.EmpName)
    <input type="hidden" asp-for="Emp.EmpName" />
    <br />

    @Html.DisplayNameFor(model => model.Emp.LeaveBalance)
    @Html.DisplayFor(model => model.Emp.LeaveBalance)
    <input type="hidden" asp-for="Emp.LeaveBalance" />
    <br />

    <input type="submit" value="Submit1" asp-page-handler="Submit1" />
    <br />
    <input type="submit" value="Submit2" asp-page-handler="Submit2" />
</form>
```

Comment: Thanks for your reply, but the attached example is easy to handle using the hidden fields, but the real scenario that the object I have includes a lot of properties (of different data types) in addition to a list of another class objects, which makes my object complex to be stored in hidden fields

Comment: OK, in real scenario, you may only need to send the unique id to the backend to get the record and modify it. Since http is stateless, you need to re-assign the modified emp to `Emp` and then the page can get the data.

Comment: I agree, this is the temp solution I used, I was trying to avoid unnecessary calls for multiple times to the backend web API, but it seems that I have to do this. Thanks for your reply again.

Comment: Hi @YoussefSalame , if my reply is helpful, could you please [mark it as answer](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/5234/how-does-accepting-an-answer-work), thanks!